# Is anyone doing iPhone SDK 2.x.x dev on Snow Leopard?

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard

There seems not to be an SDK 2.x.x for Snow Leopard.  Or am I mistaken?

BTW, I'm loving the built-in Clang!!  Kudos to the Xcode team!

Comment: I think you can still submit apps targeted for the 2.2.1 SDK, but Apple tests everything only with 3.0.

Comment: I just installed Snow Leopard tonight, redownloaded the iPhone 3.1 beta SDK and there in the installation screen was an option to install the 2.x SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write applications targeting iPhone OS 2.x for Snow Leopard. Just make sure you are not using any iPhone OS 3.0 specific API:s.

You can also write applications that target both 2.x and uses 3.0 features if available. Two things to keep in mind if you do:

- Link any iPhone OS 3.0 frameworks weakly.
- Be sure to check the `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion` before calling something 3.0-ish.

Could be a third bullet; Ask yourself if user who did not even care to upgrade to iPhone OS 3.0, is likely to care for installing apps?

Comment: People I know who haven't upgraded their iPhone, are usually those who use iTunes rarely - they're still on the same OS as when they bought their iPhone + no apps.  However, for some w/ iPod Touches, they may not have wanted/been able (think kids) to pay the upgrade fee.

See my answser from an Apple employee below for targeting 2.x.

Answer (score 6):

From Apple:

Set your Base SDK to iPhone 3.0 Device.
Set your iPhone Deployment Target to 2.2.1.
Use AvailibilityMacros when you call iPhone 3.0 APIs.

[image]

There isn't an iPhone Simulator for 2.x in Snow Leopard.  Set your Active SDK to iPhone 3.0 Simulator to test in the simulator; set it to 3.0 Device and set your Active Executable to 2.2.1 to test the app on a 2.2.1 device.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on "set your Active Executable to 2.2.1"? Did you make another build target? Also, please cite or link to the source so we can know where to look in a similar future situation.

Comment: No you don't need to make another build target.  Just go to your current target's build settings, look for iPhone OS Deployment Target.

The above is from an email, so I can't link to source, but here is pretty much the same:  https://devforums.apple.com/thread/26030

Answer (score 0):

I asked about this at WWDC and was told that the 2.2 SDK doesn't work with XCode 3.2. I tried just copying it over, and it didn't work. That said, I'm not sure how many iPhone customers are still running 2.2...

Answer (score 0):

This is a big problem because we can't test apps for OS 2.x without a device that have OS 2.x!
http://www.fdambrosio.net/archives/1395

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with supporting iPhone OS 2.x and iPhone OS 3.x related to device or interface rotation animation:

Read my blog post here:
http://blog.jessearmand.com/post/358250047/regarding-iphone-os-compatibility-and-support-of-older

Comment: This clinched it for me (even if I don't use those APIs). Looks like backwards compatibility back to 2.x is not really expected and not worth it

Comment: Definitely, I just hope there are no more problems in newer versions of the SDK.