# How do I install iPhone2.0 SDK on snow leopard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

The snow leopard xcode only installs 3.1, 3.0, and 2.2.1. I need to install 2.0 to use as the base SDK for a particular app.

I see the iPhoneSDK2_0.pkg in the Packages directory of the install image, but there is no option to install it...

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it looks like 2.2.1 is the earliest SDK supported on Snow Leopard.  The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350172/is-anyone-doing-iphone-sdk-2-x-x-dev-on-snow-leopard) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397756/developing-for-2-2-1-sdk-on-snow-leopard) describe how to use 2.2.1, but no earlier SDKs are available for Snow Leopard.  I also believe that the iPhone Simulator on Snow Leopard does not let you test against iPhone OS 2.x, only 3.x.

To be honest, there is very little reason to stick with 2.x at this point.  Satisfying the needs of the few remaing 2.x holdouts isn't worth handicapping yourself by using the older SDK.  If you're developing a for-pay application, I doubt that people unwilling to pay the $5 upgrade fee for the older iPod touches will be interested in buying your application.

Comment: Agreed - the type of person who isn't on 3 isn't the type to spend much money on apps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SDK 2.0 to compile/build iPhone OS 2.0 - compatible apps.
Simulator's "Hardware" menu allow to choose OS version for tests.

Comment: I have specific functionality that needs the base 2.0 SDK.

Comment: Actually, that's the right answer. Even if you could install the 2.0 SDK, you wouldn't be able to ship an application using it: Apple requires applications to target the 3.0 SDK now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a very good reason to continue to support iPhone OS 2.x if you have a shipping product - people who have already bought your product.  If you require OS 3.x for all future updates, you will shut customers out of updates, which means they will continue to email you or give you bad reviews about issues you've already fixed.

For this very reason, I'm sticking with Leopard for now.