# How to get back all those good old Xcode features?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, macos

After I've upgraded to Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2, everything was screwed up. It took a while for me to figure out the whole evil was that my old Xcode installation was not really "updated", but replaced. So just everything was gone. All SDKs, Settings, everything.

So Code Sense did not work because of no SDK available, and all the other problems mentioned also just appeared because of that. So now, after re-installing all SDK's, Xcode seems to work fine. Well, almost: Simulator 2.2.1 is gone, which feels more like a punishment for upgrading fast to SL.

After all I decided to re-edit my question to prevent irritations. However, here in short what problems I had, so the answers still match:

1) The font was totally different

2) New Xcode didn't autocomplete CGRectMake and provided no parameter info, for instance. That was because of all missing SDK's and my wrong believe that it was an "upgrade" rather than a whole new replace.

3) New Xcode didn't highlight same symbols in scope. Same problem cause like above.

4) New Xcode never autocompleted anything. Same problem cause like above.

Off topic, but I feel everyone in the world must know:
The new Quicktime Player sucks. They removed all important controls like speed and sound tuning, which was always welcome on bad video trainings. Hopefully, they will add those important features again soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are the first person I know of who feels that Xcode 3.2 is not a significant step forward.  In response to your issues:

1) The new default font for Xcode is Menlo, as opposed to the previous Monaco.  You can easily change this back under `Xcode | Preferences | Fonts & Colors`.  Personally, I prefer [Anonymous Pro](http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymouspro.html) or [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html).

2) It sounds like your Code Sense index for your project might be messed up, causing the autocompletion issues that you're seeing.  Click on the root of your project in Xcode, bring up the inspector, go to the General tab, and click on the `Rebuild Code Sense Index` button.  I had this happen to me once, and that took care of the problem.

3) If I double-click on a symbol to highlight it, a dashed underline does appear below all instances of the symbol within the scope.  As has been pointed out, right-clicking on the symbol will let you Edit All in Scope, a really nice addition to the editor.

4) See 2) above.

As far as the Quicktime Player, you can install the old Quicktime 7 as an optional player so that you can gain back some of the functionality that hasn't made it into the new player.  The whole point of the new player is to start from scratch with the video playback frameworks, enabling much better performance (my MacBook Air can play 720p video without stuttering now).  The missing functionality will be added back in, as it was with the new iMovie.

The point of Snow Leopard was not to remove capabilities, but to refine what was there and to strip out obsolete elements.  In the case of Xcode 3.2, they added the integrated Clang LLVM compiler team, the integrated Clang Static Analyzer (worth the upgrade alone), a much improved documentation browser, and many new capabilities to the editor (like the Edit All in Scope mentioned above).

As far as iPhone OS 2.x support, [you can build for it in Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350172), but the Snow Leopard version of the iPhone Simulator only runs the 3.x OS.  Apple clearly wants you to target the 3.x OS going forward.

Answer (score 3):

1) Change the font in the Xcode preferences.

2) Xcode preferences "Code Sense"

3) Select the symbol and hover over it, after a short delay a small grey triangle appears to the right of the symbol, left click on it and select "Edit All in Scope".  Not quite the same.

4) Same as 2 above.

Both 2 and 4 work for me, I must have different preference settings.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mac OS X 10.6.1 and Xcode 3.2:

1. My fonts are nice
2. Works for me
3. Works for me

Maybe you should try to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, all of the things you list can be addressed with preference settings in XCode - for #3, check your setting for "Edit All In Scope" under "Code Sense" in Settings.