# Xcode iPhone OS multiple versions

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a way to add earlier versions of iphone os in xcode 3.1.2, so I can build by app for different os versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is because I have had older versions of Xcode, but I can Get Info on a project and change the "Base SDK" property to an older version and then build for that, e.g. 2.2.1

Comment: You can do this only if that version of the SDK is installed.  Newer versions of Xcode don't necessarily come with all older versions of the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one app that supports a range of versions, you should set your Base SDK to the latest version you want to support.  Then set your Deployment target to the earliest version you want supported.  Then in your code, you test for availability of questionable frameworks, before you use them.

See this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350172) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it but you should have different partitions in your Mac and when you go through wizard change the default location to specific location in this new partition ,then you can use the two Xcode for earlier & latest versions as you want.