# How do I get 'iPhone Device 2.2.1' listed as one of my active SDKs in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just installed xcode on a snow leopard machine. I am wanting to compile and iPhone app with the 2.2.1 SDK.

Under `Project > Edit Project Settings` I have the option for the base SDK to be "iPhone Device 2.2.1" but I'm not getting that setting as an option for my Active SDK...

What do I need to do so I can get iPhone Device 2.2.1 listed as one of my active SDKs?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350172/is-anyone-doing-iphone-sdk-2-x-x-dev-on-snow-leopard

Comment: @Brad, not a duplicate, I'm asking how to get 2.2.1 listed as one of my active SDKs, nowhere in that question is that answered.

Answer (score 0):

To target a 2.2.1 (on Snow Leopard) you have to change your project’s “iPhone OS Deployment Target.”

It's a bit hidden in the properties of the Project (under Deployment), but here you can select 2.x.